# How to get the length of a JSON object stored in localStorage?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, local-storage

I have a REACT JS app where a JSON object **CartObj** stored in localStorage in this format:

```js
{
        "Master Automotives": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "43",
                "Name": "Oil and Lubricants",
                "Price": "4500",
                "VendorID": "48",
                "CompanyName": "Master Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "4500"

            },
            {
                "SparePartID": "45",
                "Name": "Lights",
                "Price": "2300",
                "VendorID": "48",
                "CompanyName": "Master Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "2300"
            }
        ],

        "Repair Solutions": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "47",
                "Name": "Steering Wheel",
                "Price": "1500",
                "VendorID": "60",
                "CompanyName": "Repair Solutions",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "1500"
            }
        ],
        

         "FiveStar Automotives": [
            {
                "SparePartID": "51",
                "Name": "Brakes",
                "Price": "234",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "234"
            },
            {
                "SparePartID": "53",
                "Name": "Clutch",
                "Price": "999",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "999"
            },
              {
                "SparePartID": "55",
                "Name": "LED",
                "Price": "288",
                "VendorID": "70",
                "CompanyName": "FiveStar Automotives",
                 "Qty": 1,
                 "TotalPrice": "288"
            }
        ]
    
}
```

I want to get the Length of this above **JSON Object** which is stored in my **localStorage** as "**CartObj**". As we can see the above data has total **6 (six)** distinct products so I want to get a length equal to 6.

i used the code below but it gets a very **big** **value** like 23876:

```js
const lenObj = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('storeObj'));
        const len = lenObj.length;
        console.log("JSON obj length: ",len);
```

Please **help** me how to get the length of this **JSON** Object in a correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localStorage.getItem` returns a string so you have to use `JSON.parse` not <s>JSON.stringfy</s>

And one more thing that your json is not a single array, it contains multiple arrays, if you want to count all length, you should iterate objects.

Here is the solution.

```
const lenObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storeObj'));
var count = 0;
for(var item in lenObj) {
   count += lenObj[item].length
}
console.log("JSON obj length: ",count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
const cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storeObj'));
const cartLength = Object.values(cart).flat().length;
```

Or in one line:

```
const cartLength = Object.values(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storeObj'))).flat().length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values`:

```
function getLength(obj) {
  return (Object.values(obj)).flat().length

}

console.log(getLength(obj)); // => 6
```

```js
const obj = {
 'Master Automotives': [
  {
   SparePartID: '43',
   Name: 'Oil and Lubricants',
   Price: '4500',
   VendorID: '48',
   CompanyName: 'Master Automotives',
   Qty: 1,
   TotalPrice: '4500',
  },
  {
   SparePartID: '45',
   Name: 'Lights',
   Price: '2300',
   VendorID: '48',
   CompanyName: 'Master Automotives',
   Qty: 1,
   TotalPrice: '2300',
  },
 ],

 'Repair Solutions': [
  {
   SparePartID: '47',
   Name: 'Steering Wheel',
   Price: '1500',
   VendorID: '60',
   CompanyName: 'Repair Solutions',
   Qty: 1,
   TotalPrice: '1500',
  },
 ],

 'FiveStar Automotives': [
  {
   SparePartID: '51',
   Name: 'Brakes',
   Price: '234',
   VendorID: '70',
   CompanyName: 'FiveStar Automotives',
   Qty: 1,
   TotalPrice: '234',
  },
  {
   SparePartID: '53',
   Name: 'Clutch',
   Price: '999',
   VendorID: '70',
   CompanyName: 'FiveStar Automotives',
   Qty: 1,
   TotalPrice: '999',
  },
  {
   SparePartID: '55',
   Name: 'LED',
   Price: '288',
   VendorID: '70',
   CompanyName: 'FiveStar Automotives',
   Qty: 1,
   TotalPrice: '288',
  },
 ],
};

function getLength(obj) {
  return (Object.values(obj)).flat().length

}

console.log(getLength(obj));
```